# Where is Oauth2.0 access token stored

Tags: oauth-2.0

In Oauth2 protocol flow when the client is issued an access token then where is that access token stored. How is that access token bind to the subsequent request. Is it stored in any cookie ?

Comment: Which of the flows are we talking, and what kind of client?

Comment: I am talking about client_credential flow.